# Javascript Undefined Output?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript and I can't seem to wrap my head around what is happening here.  Can someone explain why this piece of code correctly outputs data from my file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('listofwords.csv', function(err, data) {
    output = data.toString()
    console.log(output)
})
```

But when I modify the code to output the file outside of it's scope it gives me undefined:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('randomwords.csv', function(err, data) {
    output = data.toString()
    return output
})

console.log(file)
```

If you can point me to the right direction will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: [dont] use [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) for a quick fix.

Comment: That's a horrible advice @Aᴍɪʀ

Comment: `fs.readFile` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @baao I agree :D I marked it as duplicate too. just to give some other pointers to the OP, i posted the link to the sync version as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing me to the right direction. It makes more sense now. I'll dive into more about how async works.